# Is there an API for the Windows 10 instant resolution change?

Tags: windows, winapi, video, graphics, gpu

When in the Windows Settings, changing the resolution of the display will often resize the desktop without changing the graphics driver's display resolution, thus resulting in a nearly instantaneous "mode switch."

Is there a Windows API that can trigger this functionality to switch desktop resolutions?  Using ChangeDisplaySettings or ChangeDisplaySettingsEx it causes the screen to blank momentarily, even if GPU scaling is set in the graphics driver.

Comment: Are you talking about DPI changes?

Comment: No, I'm talking about display mode changes; if I say go from 1920x1080 to 1280x720 the change occurs instantly with no blanking of the screen.

Comment: It seems that if you change to 1280x720 with `ChangeDisplaySettings`, then change back to 1920x1080 with Windows Settings, there will also be a black screen momentarily.

Comment: That's because ChangeDisplaySettings shrinks the GPU's video mode and Windows has to re-expand it before it can display the higher resolution again.  When the display resolution is already high I notice Display Settings does some weird magic to bring down the desktop resolution without performing a mode switch in the driver.
I am still curious as to whether there is an API to replicate the behavior of Windows Settings and perform the software "mode switch" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings app is using this API: [`SetDisplayConfig`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setdisplayconfig).

sample:(Error checking removed)

```
#include <windows.h>


int main()
{
    UINT32 numPathArrayElements=0, numModeInfoArrayElements = 0;
    UINT32 filter = QDC_ALL_PATHS;
    GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(filter,&numPathArrayElements, &numModeInfoArrayElements);

    DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO* pathArray = new DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO[numPathArrayElements];
    DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO* modeInfoArray = new DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO[numModeInfoArrayElements];
    ZeroMemory(pathArray, sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO)* numPathArrayElements);
    ZeroMemory(modeInfoArray, sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO)* numModeInfoArrayElements);
    QueryDisplayConfig(filter,&numPathArrayElements,pathArray,&numModeInfoArrayElements,modeInfoArray,NULL);

    int ix = pathArray[0].sourceInfo.modeInfoIdx; //assuming path[0] is primary
    modeInfoArray[ix].sourceMode.width = 1280;
    modeInfoArray[ix].sourceMode.height = 720;
    SetDisplayConfig(numPathArrayElements, pathArray, numModeInfoArrayElements, modeInfoArray, SDC_APPLY | SDC_USE_SUPPLIED_DISPLAY_CONFIG | SDC_ALLOW_CHANGES | SDC_SAVE_TO_DATABASE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's it!  Thank you very much!

Comment: How do I change the BPC to 10/12/16 using the SDC call? Or is there any other way? Assume panel supports 8, 10, 12 and 16 Bits per color formats.