# Difference between ChangeDisplaySettings() vs SetDisplayConfig() to change the display resolution?

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, driver, display

I was using `ChangeDisplaySettings()` to change the resolution of a display, then I came across this: [Is there an API for the Windows 10 instant resolution change?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59064038/2183840). While searching for info about the difference between the two solutions, I found this: [What is the difference b/w ChangeDisplaySettings and SetDisplayConfig APIs wrt. Window10](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/1ad86abc-2da8-447a-84a1-b484d631ea00/what-is-the-difference-bw-changedisplaysettings-and-setdisplayconfig-apis-wrt-window10).

> I am part of Display driver debugging team. I would like to know the difference b/w ChangeDisplaySettings and SetDisplayConfig APIs wrt to Window10 ? On Window10 OS, when I try to change the mode (Resolution and RR) using:
>
> - ChangeDisplaySettings API -> Call is landing in the IHV's display driver DDI DxgkDDICommitVidpn. Able to see mode set where DWM buffers are destroyed and re-created to match the resolution size. Can see a flash (Screen goes blank for a moment) when change in mode.
> - SetDisplayConfig API -> DDI DxgkDDICommitVidpn in IHV's display driver not getting hit. It seems OS doing virtual mode set (not IHV's display driver here). Seems DWM using its existing frame buffer and scaling accordingly without real mode set. Seems here Windows10 OS virtualizing resolution, scaling and rotation change. No flash observed rather can see real time re-sizing of the desktop screen.
>
> Can anyone explain why this behavioral change in the two APIs even though both are supported by the Windows 10. Why ChangeDisplaySettings API not taking Window10's virtual mode set path?

I'm not really familiar with the topic to fully understand what's happening, but I assume that there's a difference between the two, unless DxgkDDICommitVidpn is used eventually to recreate DWM buffers of matching size, otherwise would there be a difference of performance until the driver is restarted or something? Given whatever difference there is between the two, which one should I be using if I'm only targeting Windows 10 & later, if it makes any difference at all?

Comment: SetDisplayConfig is part of CCD API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/ccd-apis) it's more recent than ChangeDisplaySettings(Ex), but they are not strictly equivalent. Some features (~GDI oriented) you will only find in ChangeDisplaySettings and friends, some other (like HDR support enable/disable) you will only find in CCD... So it really depends on what you need to do precisely. Unless there's some missing capability, I'd go for CCD.

Comment: @SimonMourier I only want to change the display resolution, everything else would remain the same, but if the description in the quoted part is right, wouldn't that mean that ChangeDisplaySettings would be better?